# How to use two FOR Loop in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, imagemagick

Can someone help me look into this? I'm trying to use Imagemagick to merge two images. One is a plain text, while the other one has a nice background. I have more than 12,000 plain text and 82 background images, so I have to construct two FOR loop to be able to pick both images randomly. But unfortunately, the second loop is not working for the background images. It only picks one and merge it with all plain text instead of random.
The following is how I am implementing it.

```
for i in $(find /home/user/png -name "*.png"); do 
    for o in $(find /home/user/jpg -name "*.jpg"); do 
       composite -gravity Center $i $o "${i%.*}.jpg"; 
    done
done
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using *any* `for` loops here. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

Answer (score 1):

> For the fact that i have more than 12,000 plain text an 82 Background so i have to construct two FOR loop for to be able to pick both image randomly.

If the background and image file paths don't contain whitespace characters,
then the following technique should work.
Replace all the `find ...` appropriately.

---

You could put the 82 background files into an array:

```
backgrounds=($(find ...))
```

Define a function to pick a random background:

```
randombg() {
    local index
    ((index = RANDOM % ${#backgrounds[@]}))
    echo ${backgrounds[index]}
}
```

And then loop over the image files, and for each file, pick a random background:

```
find ... | while read image; do
   bg=$(randombg)
   composite -gravity Center $image $bg "${image%.*}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for helping me. This works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `shuf` command to create an endless stream of shuffled **.jpg* files, which within the `for` loop are input with `read o`:

```
shuf -r -e $(find /home/user/jpg -name "*.jpg") | 
for i in   $(find /home/user/png -name "*.png") ; do 
    read o
    composite -gravity Center "$i" "$o" "${i%.*}.jpg"
done
```

Since there are no `bash` arrays, the above code is *POSIX* by default.